# Process html form and get result in Android

Tags: java, android, html

I want to process html form. This html form is on web-site, this site doesn't have API. So on this site is html form, I know action and method of this form. I want to fill this form on Android application and get result. What I must do?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FIELD1", "abc"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FIELD2", "abc"));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is my request to server. How I can get result of this request?

Comment: Every time you post a question like this you should add at least what you've tried, what didn't work and why it didn't work - it will motivate users to answer your question.

Comment: I learn about HttpClient, but I can not understand what is technology I must use for get result. So I established a connection with server:
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("url");
and get information from field:
textField1 = form.getElementById("name");

It is true or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have very detailed experience with HttpClient because in my past experiences I mostly used [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) Java library. But I also tried using HttpClient, here is a code snippet to get the content of a response.

There may be some differences related with Android  API but I hope it helps. (For instance, CloseableHttpResponse and HttpResponse )

```
public static String readHttpResponse(CloseableHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (null != entity) {
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line = null;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }

    return builder.toString();
} // end of readHttpResponse(CloseableHttpResponse response)
```

And this is a different implementation which uses EntityUtils

```
public static String readHttpResponse(CloseableHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (null != entity) {
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }

    return "";
} // end of readHttpResponse(CloseableHttpResponse response)
```

If you are interested using a library, you would get the same result using the code in the below.

```
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("URL")
            .data("FIELD1", "abc", "FIELD2", "abc")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();

    String result = res.body();
```